# Meaning of "issue" in "my trusty navy-issue peacoat"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My trusty navy-issue peacoat is old as hell

What does *issue* mean here?

Comment: It just means the peacoat was ***issued by** the navy*, as in [standard army-issue](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22standard+army-issue%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Related to *Issue (sense 2)* at [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/issue?q=issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED sense 15c for ***issue*** reads:

> An item or amount of something given out or distributed. *orig. U.S.*

And gives this specific example (amongst others):

> - 1919 *Athenæum* 8 Aug. 727/2 ― Anything supplied by the Army was an ‘issue’.

Comment: Yup; this is it – it means the jacket was given to him (or "issued by") the Navy.  It also implies the jacket was originally a navy uniform item, probably one that stayed in use even after the speaker got out of the navy.

Comment: @Theo: no.  *Navy-issue* is correct.

Comment: Oh so in this case, the speaker made a typo should have been "navy-issued" instead of "navy-issue"?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, consider also these senses of *issue*, from [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/issue):

4[UNCOUNTABLE] FORMAL the act of officially giving something to someone
the issue of visitors' permits

a.
something that is given to every member of a group
She was wearing the heavy black jacket that was standard police issue.

5[UNCOUNTABLE] LEGAL someone's children
He died without issue (=with no children).